# Weather application data structures and design

Tags: object-oriented, html, typescript

Relevant files are script.ts, WeatherData.ts, index.html.

I made a simple weather 5-day forecast application using mainly TypeScript. I was wondering how I can improve my code since I originally wanted to use a data structure that I created called a "WeatherData" to store my information about the weather for each day of the week.

[GitHub project](https://github.com/jonathanwangg/WeatherWizard)

#### WeatherData data structure

```
export class WeatherData {
    date: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    temperature: number;
    minTemperature: number;
    maxTemperature: number;
    weather: any;
    weatherIcon: any;
}
```

#### TypeScript file concerns

The main concerns I have about the TypeScript files (script.ts, WeatherData.ts) is the fact that halfway through making my project, I realized that I didn't actually need to use a `WeatherData` data structure. This led to me passing in `WeatherData` variables in functions as well as returning `WeatherData` variables from functions that don't actually need to return it.

1. Is there a more object-oriented way I should be approaching my script.ts class in order to use data structures?
2. Will using a `WeatherData` data structure be better?
3. How can I format my code (maybe different classes?) such that all the functions aren't all clumped together?

#### HTML file concerns

First time ever making a front-end UI using HTML and I don't know what areas I should refactor. I noticed I have a lot of repeated element tags such as:

```html
<h4 id="wordDay0">Day 0</h4>
<h4 id="monthDay0">month-day 0</h4>
<h4 id="forecast0">Forecast</h4>
<img src="" id="icon0" alt="" height="60" width="60">
<h1 id="currentTemp0">Current</h1>
<h4 id="maxTemp0">Max</h4>
<h4 id="minTemp0">Min</h4>
```

I have 5 of these (one for each day).

Screenshot of what the UI looks like:

[image]

1. What type of suggestions are there to making my UI look better? I was thinking of making the jumbotron element a different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unor already covered pretty much everything I would say for the HTML structure, so I will focus on [script.ts](https://github.com/jonathanwangg/WeatherWizard/blob/master/src/js/script.ts).

1. The most important advice I can give you is to get rid of `any`. By using `any` you are completely negating the advantages of using Typescript. Properly type everything possible. In this case, it looks like you are using `any` mostly for the response from the API. It would be far better to use an interface for the API response. It could look something [like this](https://gist.github.com/Gerrit0/48ff666b4322a1a1df92d568101fb8ed).
2. Avoid explicitly stating types. There is a place and time for stating what type a variable is, but it is often just more noise to read.

   ```ts
   const daysShort: string[] = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
   ```

   There is no need to state that `daysShort` is an array of strings as the compiler is smart enough to determine that itself. Personally, I try to only define types when using objects. Type inference for primitive types and arrays is generally very good.
3. Don't mix `const`/`let` and `var`. Be consistent. I recommend sticking with `const`/`let`.
4. Don't use functions that return promises as event handlers. This doesn't make sense as the event handler won't know what to do with them.
5. If using `$.ajax` don't append query parameters yourself, use the `data` property of the `settings` object. (next point)
6. `customSearch` doesn't make sense. Instantiating a promise will *never* throw an error. If you want to handle errors from the promise, you need to use `.catch(error => {})` or use `async`/`await`. It would be better to write the function like this:

   ```ts
   async function customSearch() {
     const searchParameter: string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("searchBox")).value;
     if (searchParameter === "") {
       alert("Please enter a city and it's ISO country code.")
     }

     try {
       const response: ApiResponse = await $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast", {
         data: {
           q: searchParameter,
           appid: appid
         }
       })
       if (response.cod !== "200") {
         throw new Error(response.message)
       }

       setGeneralInforation(response)
     } catch (error) {
       showError("API returned an error, invalid city / country code?");
     }
   }
   ```

   (I would make similar comments for your other search functions, and I would also personally split out the error handling from the API request so that the function would end up looking more like the following)

   ```ts
   async function customSearch(searchParameter: string): Promise<ApiOkResponse > {
     if (searchParameter === "") {
       throw new Error("Please enter a city and it's ISO country code.");
     }

     const response: ApiResponse = $.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast", {
       data: {
         q: searchParameter,
         appid: appid
       }
     })
     if (response.cod !== "200") {
       throw new Error("Invalid request: " + response.message)
     }

     return response;
   }
   ```
7. I suspect that `determineMinTemp`, `determineMaxTemp`, `determineCurrentTemp`, (or at least min/max) can be mostly combined by using a function which accepts a function as a parameter to get the correct key, but this is difficult to say without better typings, feel free to ask another question once you have incorporated suggestions from this round of reviews to see what other suggestions there may be.

There is certainly more that could be said, but I think for now I'll leave you with this so this doesn't become too overwhelming. Your project isn't a bad start!

---

A few opinionated statements that some may not agree with.

1. You probably don't need jQuery here. You essentially use it for `document.querySelector`, `.addEventListener('click', fn)`, and `fetch`. I would probably remove it.
2. Add `tslint` to the project and configure it to warn about consistent spacing (`if(` vs `if (`), this can also help with autofixing missing semicolons, etc.
3. Add `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters` to your tsconfig.json file to avoid importing code you don't need. You import `parse` from `ts-node/dist`, but don't use it.

Comment: 1. When you suggest that I use an interface instead of any for the API response, do you mean that I should create an interface like you did in the github gist file and then have some method that sets all the values?

Comment: 3. The reason I was mixing the `const` / `let` / `var` was because `let` and `var` have different scopes so that was why I chose to use them differently. I think `const` was only used at the top for `months`, `daysShort`, and `appid`.

Comment: 4. Could you explain a bit more for this one? I don't really get what you're trying to say.

Comment: 5 & 6. I will change it to your suggestions since I didn't look through the docs too carefully as I was coding the project.

Comment: 7. I'm not too experienced with passing functions as parameters. I think I'll try to refactor this after I finish everything else.

Comment: I'm having issues with installing tslint, so I think I'll just try to do that for a future TypeScript project.

Comment: 1 - I think yes, really the main thing to avoid is `any`.  3 - There's no need to ever use `var`. 4 - Returning a promise in an event listener doesn't make sense as it isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

#### About the HTML

You shouldn’t use heading elements (`h1`-`h6`) like that. These elements give the heading for the section they create. Don’t use them for the name in simple name-value items, nor for stand-alone content (where no other content in the section exists).

You could represent each day as a `section`:

```html
<section><!-- day 1 --></section>
<section><!-- day 2 --></section>
<section><!-- day 3 --></section>
<section><!-- day 4 --></section>
<section><!-- day 5 --></section>
```

A `section` should ideally have a heading (and it’s the only one needed in this case). I think it makes the most sense to use the day+date as heading. The `time` element can be used to mark up the date in a machine-readable way. The `abbr` element can be used to give the full name of the day.

```html
<h2><abbr title="Sunday">Sun</abbr> <time datetime="2017-12-31">Dec. 31</time></h2>
```

The forecast can be given in a `p`. As the `img` seems to convey the same content, it’s correct to keep the `alt` attribute empty.

```html
<p>clear sky</p>
<img src="clear-sky.png" alt="" height="60" width="60">
```

While you could use a list for the temperatures, I think three `p` elements are sufficient in this simple case.

```html
<p>14 °C</p>
<p>High: 20 °C</p>
<p>Low: 6 °C</p>
```

When using a label for the first temperature, too, I would go with a `dl` element instead:

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Current</dt> <dd>14 °C</dd>
  <dt>High</dt> <dd>20 °C</dd>
  <dt>Low</dt> <dd>6 °C</dd>
</dl>
```

---

So, an entry for a day could look like this:

```html
<section>
  <h2><abbr title="Sunday">Sun</abbr> <time datetime="2017-12-31">Dec. 31</time></h2>
  <p>clear sky</p>
  <img src="clear-sky.png" alt="" height="60" width="60">
  <p>14 °C</p>
  <p>High: 20 °C</p>
  <p>Low: 6 °C</p>
</section>
```

or with `dl`:

```html
<section>
  <h2><abbr title="Sunday">Sun</abbr> <time datetime="2017-12-31">Dec. 31</time></h2>
  <p>clear sky</p>
  <img src="clear-sky.png" alt="" height="60" width="60">
  <dl>
    <dt>Current</dt> <dd>14 °C</dd>
    <dt>High</dt> <dd>20 °C</dd>
    <dt>Low</dt> <dd>6 °C</dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll make those changes to the HTML. Just waiting for someone to answer my TypeScript questions now...